# How to create drive partitions in Windows Server 2003 Enterprise (x64)

Tags: partitioning, windows-server-2003, vmware-player

I want to create D: ,E:,and F: drives,
I have Windows Server 2003 Enterprise (x64) on vm player, i've tried :

Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Storage > Disk Management >
and right click on the C: and searched for shrink volume, but is was not there?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you simply attach extra HDD in your VM properties?
System volume cannot be shrinked with built-in tools. You need to use gparted or similar third-party software.

Comment: @user177931 - Load another VM and attached the VM HDD to that VM instance. If you do this you can do what you want.  You could if you want just duplicate the vm then change the UID on the second copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a real system, as long as there is enough free space, from Disk Manager you can shrink the active partition, no problem. Then there will be some unformatted region at the end. Create new partitions there. I'm not sure if you can do it in a virtual machine though... Try converting the dynamic virtual disk in fixed size...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot shrink system volume on running system.
options:
1) fastest and easiest one (and the best for vm as i think) is just to create few more virtual drives and attach them to vm
2) longest one - download any linux live iso, boot this vm from iso, run gparted, resize partition as you need to. reboot

Comment: Actually **YOU CAN** just not on **Windows Server 2003**.

Comment: yes, i was talking about windows server 2003 mentioned in question

Comment: So say its possible just not with the operating system in question.  Currently the statement is semi-false.